# Convert pennies to currency with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, number-to-currency

I am using Stripe and getting currency that is in pennies. So 12.90 looks like 1290. I want to convert this to U.S. Currency but if I try and use the [number_to_currency](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency) method it ends up looking like 1,290.00. Is there a method to convert the full string to currency so it comes out correctly at 12.90?

My current code is:

```
<h4>Total Payment Due: <%= number_to_currency(@user.total_cost)%>
```

Comment: I think you mean 12.90 instead of 12.95 at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just divide by 100, but make sure it's a float, ie. use 100.0 to prevent rounding to 12.00.

```
<h4>Total Payment Due: <%= number_to_currency(@user.total_cost/100.0)%>
```

That shows `$12.90`.

Comment: Just to be clear, the *result* can be a float, but not the `total_cost`; that can stay an integer.

Comment: Updated answer for clarity

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the money gem: https://github.com/RubyMoney/money

```
Money.new(100, "USD").format #=> "$1.00"
```

Might be overkill, but will do what you want.